# How to change the font color of a TrueTypeFont in a TextButton LibGDX

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx

I am trying to create a TextButton inside my application and I am using TrueType fonts(.ttf), but when I change the color of the font using rgba format with

```
 TextButtonStyle.fontColor = [a color];
```

,the color set by LibGDX is not the one I intended. I think the problem is caused by the fact that the font already has a color set in its parameters and it is interfering with the one I am setting. How could I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Set white color in  `FreeTypeFontParameter`'s attribute and required color in Style.

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("xyz.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.color = Color.WHITE;
```

You must set the r, g, b and alpha component as floats in the range [0,1].

Answer (score 0):

The code Abhishek provided is going to work fine and if you wanna provide your own custom color you can do it like this:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("myFont.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.color = new Color(235/255f,73/255f,78/255f,1);
```